# Improving quick sort algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, quick-sort

I'm learning algorithm and this is my implementation of quick sort, please guide how can i improve it further and what are other more optimal ways to implement quick sort?

```
def quick_sort(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    if length <= 1:
        return arr

    else:
        pivot = arr.pop()

    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in arr:
        if item > pivot:
            items_greater.append(item)
        else:
            items_lower.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_lower)+[pivot]+quick_sort(items_greater)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your indentation is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unnecessary `else:`

```
    if length <= 1:
        return arr

    else:
        pivot = arr.pop()

    ...
```

If the first path is taken, the method exits.  If the second path is taken, then execution continues with the remainder of the method.  So you could write the rest of the method inside the `else:` clause:

```
    if length <= 1:
        return arr

    else:
        pivot = arr.pop()

        ...  # Now part of the else statement
```

Or, for more "left leaning" code, remove the `else:` clause altogether:

```
    if length <= 1:
        return arr

    pivot = arr.pop()

    ...
```

## Loop like a native

```
    items_greater = []
    items_lower = []

    for item in arr:
        if item > pivot:
            items_greater.append(item)
        else:
            items_lower.append(item)
```

Here, you are creating a list, and then calling `.append()` to repeatedly add items to that list in a loop.  Python has a builtin mechanism to do this, faster.  List comprehension:

```
    items_greater = [item for item in arr if item > pivot]
    items_lower = [item for item in arr if not(item > pivot)]
```

Why `not(item > pivot)`, and not simply `item <= pivot`?  For the most part, the latter will work.  But there are gotchas and special cases.  If there are infinities (`+Inf`, `-Inf`) or a not-a-numbers (`NaN`) in the list, items might be omitted from both lists.  For example, if the list contains a `NaN`, both `NaN > 10` and `NaN <= 10` are `False`, which would result in that item not being added to either the `items_greater` or the `items_lower` lists!  Worse, if `pivot` happened to become `NaN`, then all `arr` items would be excluded!  Similarly, if there are two infinities in the list, both `+Inf > +Inf` and `+Inf <= +Inf` are `False`.

## PEP-8

The [PEP-8](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=PEP-8&s=d) coding standard has many suggestion about how to format code.  Binary operators, for example, should have a single space on either side of the binary operator.

```
    return quick_sort(items_lower)+[pivot]+quick_sort(items_greater)
```

should be:

```
    return quick_sort(items_lower) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_greater)
```

Comment: Would you expect the list comprehension to go faster? It's doing two passes instead of one.

Answer (score 3):

[Document your code. In the code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring): while
 `quick_sort(arr)` is telling to an extent (*sort into (ascending "natural") order (between pairs of `arr`'s elements), additional space no worse than proportional to input size, processing time no worse than proportional to its square*),
 `arr` isn't: what, in Python, is an array? The way `arr` is used, any [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) would do nicely -
  for lack of a useful docstring, I'd have to inspect the code to find out.
And does `quick_sort(arr)` keep the relative order of *equal* items?
Does it return something useful? What, exactly?
Does it sort *in place*? (Modify `arr` (if not ordered) (most implementations of *quicksort* do), use additional space negligible compared to `arr`'s size)

- ***Keep promises***, explicit or implied
  For all I can see, your code uses additional space proportional to the square of `length`, worst case: *not tolerable* for a "production" implementation

While it is feasible to prevent disadvantageous splits via pivot choice, it is much simpler to [reduce ill effects on space requirements using recursion for the non-larger partition, only, and iterating on the non-smaller one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations).